# getting error while opening excel workbook in scheduled agent

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I got a problem in scheduled agent in lotus script while opening csv workbook.It simply opens workbook from Excel and reads the data.

It works perfectly fine when I run manually. It throws when schedule at workbooks.open line.

Agents Settings : Allow resticted operations with full admin rights.

Code :

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = False
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Print "New filepath=" & filepath
xlApp.Workbooks.Open filepath   ' Open the CSV file
Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
Set xlSheet = xlWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

filepath=C:\Temp\transit_15102008.csv

Error thrown at log.nsf

```
printing: ERROR : Transfer Files agent- Microsoft Office Excel: Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Temp\transit_15102008.csv'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook. at line-55
```

There is only one worksheet in the Excel.

I am not able to figure out the issue.  Please somebody help me to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install MS Office on your Domino Server?

Comment: Ms office 2007 Installed on the widows server2008 (Domino 8.5.2). In fact I am taking remote of the server and running it manually. It works fine. It is scheduled on same machine only. But throws above error.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your agent manually, it runs in your workstation context where (I assume) there is MS Office installed.

But when your agent runs as scheduled, it runs in the server context, and if you don't have MS Office installed on the server, or there's no file on the path: `C:\Temp\transit_15102008.csv` **on the server**, then your agent fails.

Solution:

1. Make sure you have MS Office properly installed on the server where your scheduled agent runs.
2. Make sure that there is file present on the path `C:\Temp\transit_15102008.csv` on your server where your scheduled agent runs.

Comment: Ms office 2007 Installed on the widows server2008 (Domino 8.5.2). In fact I am taking remote of the server and running it manually. It works fine. It is scheduled on same machine only. But throws above error.

Comment: when your agent is running this file is not taken by another process (i.e MS Office is closed). Am I right ?

Comment: I am downloading a excel attachment from notes mail and storing it in C:\Temp\transit_15102008.csv path. Then opening the excel. I checked that Ms Office is closed only . I have scheduled agent for every 5mins and monitored. Even If I hardcode the path , it is returning same error when schedule. Is there any permission setting to be changed?? . Anyway Let me check the same agent with local server and come back.

Comment: is that possible that this file is being taken by process created by previous run of your scheduled agent ? Do you free and close resources when all operations are done ?

Comment: Also if you detach file to the filesystem in the same scheduled agent, make sure that it is allowed for the agent. Check `security` tab in the agent settings and allow restricted operations for this agent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. You are very helpful. 1.Agent security is already set to allow restricted with full admin rights <br></br> 2. I have taken local copy and put in local server. It works fine when scheduled also in local server. . What could be the issue? signing? server document setting?

Comment: Is that possible that server (not you) does not have permissions to write to the `C:\Temp` folder? Check this folder permissions and try to extract files to root of drive `C` and delete them when they are processed. If it works, then the problem is in permissions on write operation to the `C:\Temp` folder.

Comment: Hi Rafael, It is downloading the file to specified path. But when it reads(opening workbook) , It throws error. I have created replica and changed the agent running server to another production server. It works fine now.